# Run other query instead of current one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, metabase

I'm using Metabase for analytics. Sometimes it counts table rows.
I catch its query

```
SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "dbo"."TableName"
```

But the problem is that TableName isn't a table, it's a view.
This view is a union of many tables. That query runs very long time. Instead of SELECT COUNT I'd like to use

```
SELECT row_count FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

In that case, I get the result instantly.
Is there any possibility to replace metabase's query with my query?
Thanks

Comment: If you want actual counts, you need to count the tables. The Sys table Is approximate

Comment: In my case it is suitable

Comment: Yeh ok, I tried looking for you but can't find